# What does (Death comes as the end) mean?

Tags: expressions

My friend and I are having a debate on what does the title of the book (Death comes as the end) actually mean.

Since both of us are not native English speakers, we can't reach a definitive answer. All on account of the use of (as) in the title.

I am arguing that (as) in the title references a point in time:
- Death comes as the end [comes].

While my friend suggests that (as) is equivalent to (like):
- Death comes "like the end".

The book has been translated to Arabic: في النهاية يأتي الموت
Which when translated literally back to English you would get: At the end, death comes. That does not help much in our debate.

Comment: You are right because "the end"  denotes a time or date. For your friend to be right, the same sentence should have been "death comes as an end."

Comment: Both meanings are possible. And it's possible that the author was being intentionally ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The novel is by Agatha Christie, who wrote many detective stories in which murders are solved. As the characters in this novel include a mortuary priest it seems the title is some punning - on both the idea that we all shall die and that her story includes a death.